# Can't approve a valid paypal billing agreement

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I'm trying to set up recurring billing with paypal and have trouble approving a valid billing agreement.

It fails with a generic error message after i create the billing agreement, click on the approval url and login with a test-buyer-account.

[image: Generic error message after logging in with test buyer]

In fact that problem is reproducible with a fresh installation of the **PayPal-PHP-SDK**.
After downloading it, installing the dependencies with `composer install`, updating `sample/bootstrap.php` with my test-application credentials, running `sample/billing/CreateBillingAgreementWithPayPal.php` and clicking on the approval url i have the exact same problem.

Here is some information about the request and response object. Did i maybe miss something?

[image: PayPal PHP SDK Sample - Create Billing Agreement]

Does anyone have an idea how i can fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching i found out that this is a regional problem, as paypals billing agreements are not available in germany.
I wish the error message from paypal would be more descriptive.

Related links:

[Example "Create Billing Agreement With PayPal" does not seem to work in sandbox](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/699)

[Approve billing plan does not work](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/300)